# am trying to retain div on page exit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retain div on exiting a page and am not very sure how to go about this, I am aware that I can achieve this using localStorage but cannot figure out how, here is the script

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv() {
        var ddlPassport = document.getElementById("ddlPassport");
        var dvPassport = document.getElementById("dvPassport");
        dvPassport.style.display = ddlPassport.value == "Y" ? "block" : "none";
  
  
  
  
  
  
  var ddlPassport = document.getElementById("ddlPassport");
        var dvPassports = document.getElementById("dvPassports");
        dvPassports.style.display = ddlPassport.value == "N" ? "block" : "none";
    }
    
</script>
```

```html
<span>Do you have Passport?</span>
    <select id = "ddlPassport" onchange = "ShowHideDiv()">
        <option value="N">No</option>
        <option value="Y">Yes</option>            
    </select>
<!--<hr />-->
<div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
    Passport Number:
    <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" />
</div>

<div id="dvPassports" style="display: none">
    Other Number:
    <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumbers" />
</div>
```

thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "retain div", what are you really trying to do (the page's behavior)?

Answer (score -1):

In the `beforeunload` of the `window` object, set whatever you like into `localStorage`.

Also, it's better to use CSS classes than to apply individual style properties.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var ddlPassport = document.getElementById("ddlPassport");
  var dvPassport = document.getElementById("dvPassport");
  var dvPassports = document.getElementById("dvPassports");

  var passNum = document.getElementById("txtPassportNumber");
  var passNums = document.getElementById("txtPassportNubmers");

  ddlPassport.addEventListener("change", ShowHideDiv);
  
  // Restore prior saved data:
  if(localStorage.getItem("passportNumber")){
    passNum.value = localStorage.getItem("passportNumber");
    ShowHideDiv();
  } else if(localStorage.getItem("passportNumbers")) {
    passNums.value = localStorage.getItem("passportNumbers");  
    ShowHideDiv();
  }
  
   
  var numElement = null;

  function ShowHideDiv() {
    if(this.value === "y"){
      dvPassport.classList.remove("hidden");
      dvPassports.classList.add("hidden");
      numElement = dvPassport;
    } else if(this.value === "n") {
      dvPassport.classList.add("hidden");
      dvPassports.classList.remove("hidden"); 
      numElement = dvPassports;
    } else {
      dvPassport.classList.add("hidden");
      dvPassports.classList.add("hidden");       
    }
  }

  // As the user is leaving the page, store the text value:
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(){
    if(numElement === dvPassport){
      localStorage.setItem("passportNumber", passNum.value);
    } else if(numElement === dvPassports) {
      localStorage.setItem("passportNumbers", passNums.value);  
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<span>Do you have Passport?</span>
    <select id = "ddlPassport">
        <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
        <option value="n">No</option>
        <option value="y">Yes</option>            
    </select>



  <div id="dvPassport"  class="hidden">
    Passport Number:
    <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber">
  </div>

  <div id="dvPassports" class="hidden">
    Other Number:
    <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumbers">
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your time, basically, I need to show a specific div depending on a selection from the dropdown list bar (yes or no). There should also be an additional item in the select bar called Select that will be disabled. If yes or no is selected the appropriate div will be displayed, and retained if the page is reloaded, however if neither option is selected, and the page is reloaded, the divs will remain hidden. I hope I have explained what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Scott, firstly thank you for your time. I am very new to javascript and am having problems getting the script to work correctly, the divs appear when each option is selected from the list bar, however on reloading the page the divs still disappear. It looks like I have copied the code you provided incorrectly but am not sure where I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: @saco `localStorage` does not work when you test your page on a local file system. You need to access the page from a web server.

Comment: Hi, I have tested the script on a webserver and its almost there, but I need to keep :<div id="dvPassport"  class="hidden">
    Passport Number:
    <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber">
  </div>

Comment: @saco I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Hi, I have tested the script on a webserver and its almost there, but I need to keep "Other Number" & textfield on the page after a reload if dropdown select is no, and "Passport number" & textfield on the page after reload if dropdown select is yes,  as well as having the saved textfield values.

Comment: Hi Scott, I have a couple of problems that I have tried to resolve without success. When "---Select---" option is clicked, it shows 
"Other Number" and its text field rather than nothing. When "Yes" option is clicked, its shows "Passport Number" and its
text field which is correct, however when the page is refreshed, it shows "Other Number" and its text field. "No" option works fine.
Thank you very much for your time and patience!.

Comment: @saco I have again updated the code. Please understand that my answer provides everything you need to make this work. If one aspect of it doesn't quite meet your needs, take a look at the code and the logic of it and tweak that section. In this case, a small modification to the `if/then` was all that was needed. We're not here to write your entire application for you. But, we are here to provide enough explanation and guidance for you to take what we are providing and run with it.

Comment: ok, many thanks for your time, am just very new to javascript and am trying to resolve the issues as best I can, I really appreciate your input.